# Sorting priority for specific Woocommerce checkout fields depending on country

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, hook-woocommerce

In Woocommerce, I need to set the default ordering priority (sorting) of three fields on the checkout page:

The first change depends on the choice of the **`'IT'`** country code:

- postcode - 'priority' => 91,

The other two are free of conditions, I just need to set the default priority:

- billing_email - 'priority' => 30,
- billing_phone - 'priority' => 40,

By editing the file directly, [class-wc-countries.php](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Countries.html#929-937) core file as shown below, I get what I need. But clearly at each update of the plugin I lose the changes.

Now I'm looking for a hook to get this done in a clean way.

In [class-wc-countries.php](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Countries.html#929-937) (around line 935) from:

```
IT' => array(
    'postcode' => array(
        'priority' => 65, // <============= HERE
    ),
    'state'    => array(
    'required' => true,
    'label'    => __( 'Province', 'woocommerce' ),
    ),
),
```

I change the 'priority' value from **`65`** to **`91`**:

```
IT' => array(
    'postcode' => array(
        'priority' => 91, // <============= HERE
    ),
    'state'    => array(
    'required' => true,
    'label'    => __( 'Province', 'woocommerce' ),
    ),
),
```

And arround line 1203 in:

```
  // Add email and phone fields.
  if ( 'billing_' === $type ) {
      $address_fields['billing_phone'] = array(
          'label'        => __( 'Phone', 'woocommerce' ),
          'required'     => true,
          'type'         => 'tel',
          'class'        => array( 'form-row-wide' ),
          'validate'     => array( 'phone' ),
          'autocomplete' => 'tel',
          'priority'     => 100, // <============= HERE
      );
      $address_fields['billing_email'] = array(
          'label'        => __( 'Email address', 'woocommerce' ),
          'required'     => true,
          'type'         => 'email',
          'class'        => array( 'form-row-wide' ),
          'validate'     => array( 'email' ),
          'autocomplete'=>'no'===get_option
              ('woocommerce_registration_generate_username' )
              ? 'email' : 'email username',
          'priority'     => 110, // <============= HERE
       );
    }
```

I change the 'priority' values to:

```
  // Add email and phone fields.
  if ( 'billing_' === $type ) {
      $address_fields['billing_phone'] = array(
          'label'        => __( 'Phone', 'woocommerce' ),
          'required'     => true,
          'type'         => 'tel',
          'class'        => array( 'form-row-wide' ),
          'validate'     => array( 'phone' ),
          'autocomplete' => 'tel',
          'priority'     => 40, // <============= HERE
      );
      $address_fields['billing_email'] = array(
          'label'        => __( 'Email address', 'woocommerce' ),
          'required'     => true,
          'type'         => 'email',
          'class'        => array( 'form-row-wide' ),
          'validate'     => array( 'email' ),
          'autocomplete'=>'no'===get_option
              ('woocommerce_registration_generate_username' )
              ? 'email' : 'email username',
          'priority'     => 30, // <============= HERE
       );
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using available filter hook you can make that change without overriding core files…

The first change is made with this hook *(for "IT" country code)*:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_country_locale', 'custom__country_locale', 30, 1 );
function wps_select_order_meta_keys( $locale ) {
    $locale['IT']['postcode']['priority'] = 91;
    return $locale;
}
```

For the second change **you need also to change the class**. It's the same code that you already have in the answer to your other question, but without this line to be removed:

```
if( ! is_account_page() ) return $fields;
```

The code is:

```
add_filter(  'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'custom_billing_fields', 20, 1 );
function custom_billing_fields( $fields ) {

    ## ---- 1.  Sort billing email and phone fields ---- ##

    $fields['billing_email']['priority'] = 30;
    $fields['billing_email']['class'] = array('form-row-first');
    $fields['billing_phone']['priority'] = 40;
    $fields['billing_phone']['class'] = array('form-row-last');

    return $fields;
}
```

> So if you remove `if( ! is_account_page() ) return $fields;` from [**the code in my other answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49641954/3730754), **it will work also on checkout page** (as as already indicated)…

So you can use (for both account and checkout pages):

```
add_filter(  'woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'custom_default_address_fields', 20, 1 );
function custom_default_address_fields( $fields ) {

    ## ---- 1.  Remove 'address_2' field ---- ##

    unset($fields['address_2']);

    ## ---- 2.  Sort Address fields ---- ##

    // Set the order (sorting fields) in the array below
    $sorted_fields = array('first_name','last_name','company','address_1','country','postcode','city','state');

    $new_fields = array();
    $priority = 0;

    // Reordering billing and shipping fields
    foreach($sorted_fields as $key_field){
        $priority += 10;

        if( $key_field == 'company' )
            $priority += 20; // keep space for email and phone fields

        $new_fields[$key_field] = $fields[$key_field];
        $new_fields[$key_field]['priority'] = $priority;
    }
    return $new_fields;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Perfect always better.
So I have functions that already reordered the fields in the checkout and now come into conflict with these new additions.
So I need time for better integration.
I'll let you know as soon as possible.
As always, thanks in advance ...... :)

Comment: @Dom you can also Use [conditional woocommerce functions](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/) as `is_checkout()` and `is_account()` but if you use the same hooks change the priority of the hook that is the **3rd argument** in `add_action()`and  `add_filter()` (a different one each time just for same hooks)