# Labels and Values are not shown properly in my-account/edit-address/ after I removed some fields

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In Woocommerce, I have added the following code to my theme's `functions.php` file to remove the zip/state fields in /my-account/edit-address/billing:

```
 add_filter('woocommerce_address_to_edit', 'reorder_woocommerce_address_fields', 10, 2);
function reorder_woocommerce_address_fields( $address, $load_address) {
    $new_address['billing_first_name'] = $address['billing_first_name'];
    $new_address['billing_last_name'] = $address['billing_last_name'];
    $new_address['billing_email'] = $address['billing_email'];
    $new_address['billing_phone'] = $address['billing_phone'];

    $new_address['billing_email'] = array(
        'label'     => __('Email', 'woocommerce'),
        'required'  => true,
        'class'     => array('form-row-first'),
    );

    $new_address['billing_phone'] = array(
        'label'     => __('Phone', 'woocommerce'),
        'required'  => true,
        'class'     => array('form-row-last'),
        'clear'     => true
    );

    $new_address['billing_company'] = $address['billing_company'];
    $new_address['billing_country'] = $address['billing_country'];
      $new_address['billing_city'] = $address['billing_city'];
    $new_address['billing_address_1'] = $address['billing_address_1'];

    return $new_address;
}
```

It is based on *"[Customizing my-account addresses fields in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49641316/customizing-my-account-addresses-fields-in-woocommerce-3/49641781#49641781)"* answer code and it removes the fields…

But there is still an error message saying that **the state and zip fields are required**. So I added this:

```
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields' , 'custom_override_default_address_fields' );
 function custom_override_default_address_fields( $address_fields ) {
      global $woocommerce;
      $country = $woocommerce->customer->get_country();
      if($country !== 'US'){
         $address_fields['state']['required'] = false;
         $address_fields['postcode']['required'] = false;
      }
      return $address_fields;
 }
```

Now address is saved normally but when I am being redirected to /my-account/edit-address/, I see only this:

[image]

Where: 
Konstantine - is billing_first_name 
Berulava - is billing_last_name 
Odelia Studio - is billing_company 
Digomi - is billing_address_1 
Tbilisi - is billing_city

I don't see labels and some fields also are missing.

Any suggestions on what to do?