# Customizing my-account addresses fields in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

first_name -

Last name (not required )

email (not required)

- phone

company (not required)

address_1

postcode (not required)

city (not required)

state (not required)

Country

Answer (score 0):

You can check this thread that has the same thing as you want,

[custimizing my-account address fields woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49641316/customizing-my-account-addresses-fields-in-woocommerce-3)

Hope it will help you!

Comment: If you know coding , please give me fresh code , so i can put in function.php file

Answer (score 0):

You can check the link, it has the code to remove the fields that you do not want to use in the my-account. e.g if you want to remove the field like last name then you can write the
`last_name`

```
// Account Edit Adresses: Remove fields 
add_filter('woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'custom_default_address_fields', 20, 1 );

function custom_default_address_fields( $fields ) { 

// Only on account pages 

if( ! is_account_page() ) return $fields;

     ## ---- 1. Remove 'last_name' field ---- ## 
     unset($fields['last_name']); 

}
```

you can write this in your function file.

Comment: What about state selection , i don't want customer to enter state mandatory

Comment: This helps in only billing address not in shipping address